# how to move to the page i want in pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf

i am working on generating a pdf file of multiple pages but when i am adding my information to the pdf file this information is added only in the last page and the previous pages are empty, this is a part of my code and i need to start from the first page and then move to the second according to a condition, where in every page i want only 20 rows of data.
is there any solution??

```
try {
            Document d = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            d.open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < 3; ++currentPage) {
                d.newPage();
                PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(pageWidth, pageHeight);
                Graphics2D g2d = new PdfGraphics2D(template, pageWidth, pageHeight * (currentPage + 1));
                d.setPageCount(currentPage + 1);
                g2d.dispose();
                cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
            }
            cb.beginText();
            cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "FULL NAME:", 10, 820, 0);
            cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Age:", 10, 810, 0);
            cb.endText();
            cb.eoFill();
            d.close();
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: Well, you only add visible content to the last page, so obviously prior pages are empty. If you want content on the earlier pages, too, add it.

Comment: So where i should add the visible content in the code for all pages?

Comment: Before you call `d.newPage()` to proceed to the next page, make sure that you have added all the content you want on that page, be it by `d.add` calls or by operations on the direct content `cb`.. BTW, what do you need that `PdfTemplate` with that `PdfGraphics2D` for? They are completely empty after all.

Comment: I used them to make the page appears as A4 i dont know if that is a good idea but i am trying to improve my code.

Comment: You can choose the page size A4 using `Document d = new Document(PageSize.A4)` but this already is the default; Thus, you should get A4 PDFs anyway